# xlwings standalone addin missing function ConvertToUTC

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have created an Excel file and .py file using
`xlwings quickstart hello --standalone` which works fine. But when I run the macro that should print "hello" in A1, I get an error saying "ConvertToUTC Sub or Function not defined". I understand the error but I'm rather puzzled by how a function can be missing.

Can the function be found somewhere so that I can add it? Or is there another solution?

Comment: See https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/2290

Comment: @FelixZumstein, thanks. That was me asking that :)